# how to get the dynamic ID of Div once added? (CasperJS)

Tags: javascript, css-selectors, google-plus, casperjs

Currently I'm using casperJS v1.1
and also phantomJS v2.1.1

and right now, I'm trying to make a JS that emulate posting
mechanism through out the code.

Several checklists:

1. login to account.google.com V done.
2. visit plus.google.com V done.
3. get the textbox (share status) V done.
4. change the value of 3rd step X trouble.
5. click the button (share status) X trouble.

I'm currently in the 4th step (Second Picture)
I'm unable to get the Dynamic ID of an element. Coz i want to fill in some value inside it.

Please look at the pictures to see my situation.

[image: Firstly I'm able to get the textbox and click on it via casperJS]
[image: Second, this is the case, i'm unable to change the value -fill in value]

Here is my CasperJS Code after successfully loggin in, then visit the plus.google.com page. Check this out:

```
this.thenOpen(urlGooglePlus, function() {

                        this.capture('2_googledone_.png');
                        console.log('done capturing');

                        // clicking the div for making
                        // the textbox appeared
                        this.click(textboxSelectorBefore);
                        this.wait(2000, function(){

                            console.log('now we are inside div- status');

                            this.on('remote.message', function(msg) {
                                this.echo(msg);
                            })

                            this.evaluate(function(){
                                console.log('trying to write');
                                // it is basically :2o.f in String
                                var textboxSelector = '#dynamicID';
                                var n = document.getElementById(textboxSelector);
                                console.log('step 1');
                                if(n==null){
                                    console.log('Failed');
                                }else{
                                    console.log('We got the object');
                                }

                            });

                            console.log('done writing 3');
                            this.capture('3_googledone_.png');

                        });



                    });
```

Comment: The page has a specific structure. You can build a rigid and long CSS selector instead of relying on the dynamic ID/class. Whether there are shorter selectors that are good depends on the surrounding markup.

Comment: Sorry, but.... specific structure, for sure yes. But.... then,... how to deal with it? Sometimes the ID is changed dynamically while visiting that page, sometimes ":2o.f" sometimes ":2o.g", etc..... @ArtjomB.

Comment: As I said, you have to find another way to select the element. CSS selectors are pretty powerful. Don't give up when you're presented with some dynamic strings. Take it as a challenge to learn more about CSS selectors.